# PowerBI DAX - IF with AND / OR

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax

I am sure this is a simple question but I have tried a few versions found on here and can't seem to get the syntax right. Have also tried using SWITCH function and similarly encountered errors with the code.

Essentially, I want to mark each record with an 'Overdue' indicator based on the following logic. Within my data, some records have a Target Date populated but many are null. For the records that are null, I want to use the Action Due Date to determine if it is overdue or not.

IF 'STATUS' is not 'CLOSED' AND 'TARGET DATE' less than today = Overdue
OR
IF 'STATUS' is not 'CLOSED' AND 'ACTION DUE DATE' less than today = Overdue
ELSE Not Overdue

The DAX I am trying to write is like this :

```
 Overdue = 
 IF('Table'[Status] <>"Closed" && 'Table'[Target Date]<Today(), "Overdue", OR(
 IF('Table'[Status] <>"Closed" && 'Table'[Action Due Date]<Today(), "Overdue",
 "Not Overdue")))
```

Sorry for the dumb question, really struggling with the progression to DAX from Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this then

```
IF(
    OR(
      'Table'[Status] <>"Closed" && 'Table'[Target Date]<Today()
      ,'Table'[Status] <>"Closed" && 'Table'[Action Due Date]<Today()
    )
    ,"Overdue"
    ,"Not Overdue"
)
```

Comment: Hi Mik, thanks for your response.

I think the reason I need some kind of OR clause is because of the set up of my data. Some records have a 'Target Date' populated and some have an 'Action Due Date' populated. If one is populated, the other will be null.

I have tried your code however it results in ALL records being marked 'Overdue', which is not the case.

Comment: The OR syntax is - OR(<logical1>,<logical2>) .  You have only one statment in the OR. I've changed the code. Just check.